# Wordpress admin option, I can't use jquery ajax to access my content from another file

Tags: wp-admin

Am trying to access contents using jquery ajax in wordpress admin panel but I can't, If I try to inspect  element the error which am getting is file not found

```
http://192.168.0.67/collections/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-scraper.php Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

And the url is changing http://192.168.0.67/collections/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-scraper.php yet am using different file location

Comment: show your code, or it is as if you never asked anything.

Comment: Mark I have included the source code am just waiting for your respond